# Application_BeginRequest not firing (NOT URL rewrite)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, httprequest, global-asax

I would like to write out incoming requests for a SOAP web service.  Turns out that my Application_BeginRequest event is not firing.  It is running on IIS6 & Windows 2003, so the config change recommended elsewhere doesn't have any effect.

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength];

```
    HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Read(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);

    string requestString = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(inputBytes);

    Logger.Write("input: " + Convert.ToString(inputBytes.Length), Global.LOGGER_EVENT_SOURCE, 0, 0, TraceEventType.Warning);
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\requests\testfile - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddYYYYhhmmssffff") + ".xml"))
    {
        writer.Write(requestString);
        writer.Close();
    }

    // Reset stream pointer to beginning.
    HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Error handling; omitted here.
}
```

}

The code 'almost' works if I just put it inside of the web service method being called; the file is created but the request has a content length of '0'.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this issue is that the site is not set as an Application.

Comment: I remember once upon a time there being a distinction between a 'web site' and a 'web application', but I didn't think that this existed anymore.  I believe that it is a web application, but I will look into this, since it is not something that I have looked into either in the IDE or on the web server.